# How can you "embed" an interface in a Java class like in Go?

Tags: java, oop, interface

In Go you do the following:

```
package main

type Interface interface {
    doSomething() error
    doAnotherThing() error
}
type MyImplementation struct {
    Interface
}

func (i *MyImplementation) doSomething() error {
    return nil
}
```

You can implement some methods of the interface and leave the rest to the embedded interface.

Suppose I want to do the same in Java and partly implement an interface of 20 or more methods but don't want to write out every single method and call my underlying interface.

I don't have control over the interface as it is in a library I'm using.
Is this possible in Java or do I have to write out the whole interface?

Comment: Try the Abstract class in Java

Comment: I don't have control over the interface as it is in a library, does the abstract class method still work? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No you can't do that in Java.**

You can implement only some methods in abstract classes but can't use those as actual implementations (You can't create them with `new`).

To use a non abstract class as your interface you need to write out every single method and call your underlying instance in each call.

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract class, implementing the interface, to put only some common method implementations, and then create normal classes, extending the abstract class, for remaining specific methods implementations.

Something like this:

```
//don't touch the interface if its already there
interface Interface {
    public void  doSomething();
    public void doAnotherThing();
}

//use abstract class for common implementations
abstract class PartialClass implements Interface{
    @Override
    public void  doSomething() {
        System.out.println("doing someting in common code");
    }
    //no need to implement all the methods 
}

//create classes for specific implementations
class MyImplementation1 extends PartialClass {
    @Override
    public void doAnotherThing() {
        System.out.println("doing another thing in specific code");
    }
}

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Interface object = new MyImplementation1();
        object.doSomething();
        object.doAnotherThing();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
doing someting in common code
doing another thing in specific code
```

Comment: As I mentioned I want to partly implement an interface which has 20 or more methods, so I don't want to write them all out as I only want to override some. You just implemented both which doesn't help me. If you could show how to implement just one but it still can be used as the interface that would answer my question.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: This answer would be very helpful, but unfortunately I can't edit the interface (it is in a library I am using) so I can't define default methods.

Comment: Ok I get it now. Updated the answer. Create an abstract class to put common methods. And normal classes for specific remaining methods.

Comment: Intellij doesn't complain about the missing methods in the abstract class, in the implementation it does however and prompts me to implement the remaining methods (Which I want to delegate to my underlying interface). How can I make Java delegate these missing methods to my interface instance so I only need to implement some and the rest are forwarded? You ended up implementing both methods one in the abstract class and one in the actual implementation which I don't want to do (20 or more methods to implement by hand just to call the underlying interface every time).

Comment: If you want to forward then make that class `abstract` as well. But your last class in the hierarchy must implement remaining methods. You have to have a class which has either inherited or implemented  all the methods. If you are not using all methods then put dummy implementations in abstract class.

Comment: Thats a bummer. If thats the case, the answer to my question would be: No, that's not possible in java as you need to implement all methods eventually. I think I will answer my own question now. Thanks for the effort tho.

Comment: missing methods can also be implemented in an anonymous class direct in some method (kind of inline) but at the end all methods must be defined (additionally,interfaces can also define default methods)